# HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress- not able to fetch the IP address from WIndows se and is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip, httpcontext

I am trying to get the hostname by using the ip address of the windows server that is making the web service call by using HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress. But it is returning null for one server and working fine for other serveers. The server where it is not fetching the ip address, there WINS has been disabled. Is that the case of not fetching the ip address or any other issue.
I have authentication mode as windows in config file.

The exception is:**No such host is known**

Code Snippet:

```
public int Rtc(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            string User = GetHostNameByIP(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);

           //Other functionalities 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            msg.MessageText = string.Format(Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            bsllogger.LogInfo(msg);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

When its trying to fetch the USerHostAddress, it is throwing exception : No such host known.
This is the code for method GetHostnameByIP, but I don't think this is the issue, because if I am giving a static parameter(ip address) it is able to fetch the hostname. But as i check in my logs entry it is not fetching the dynamic ip address and its value is null so in return this method is not executing and throwing exception.

```
public string GetHostNameByIP(string ipAddress)
    {
        string hostname = string.Empty;

        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            if (!entry.HostName.ToUpper().Contains("MININT"))
                hostname = entry.HostName;
            else
                hostname = "ProcessWinpe";
        }

        return hostname;
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: @John Why would you say that?!

Comment: @Priyanka Show us actual code and error messages please

Comment: @John I suspect they meant to type "Windows Server" like the other times in the post

Comment: @John it was a typing mistake its actually Windows Server, Its a Windows 2012 r2 server.

Comment: @DavidG I have updated the question with the code snippet, please check once.

Comment: Included the code for gethostnamebyIP method @John